# How to use external entities in XML?

Tags: xml, entity

I am trying to understand how to use external entities, but I am missing something.

I have a first file, **test_entity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<test>
    <test_1>Inside</test_1>
</test>
```

And a second file **test_entity2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
    <!ENTITY test_entity SYSTEM "/Users/username/test_entity.xml">  
    <!ENTITY test_string "This is a test">
]>
<root>
    <tmp id="1">&test_entity;</tmp>
    <tmp id="2">&test_string;</tmp>
</root>
```

Here I am trying to embed test_entity.xml content into test_entity2.xml but the ouput looks like this :

```
<root>
    <tmp id="1"/>
    <tmp id="2">This is a test</tmp>
</root>
```

What am I missing ?

**Update**

I am displaying test_entity2.xml through firefox and chrome

Comment: What you have done is correct. How are you verifying the output(opening the XML in a browser, running through an identity transform, etc)?  Are you sure that the path to `test_entity` is correct?

Comment: "The ou[t]put looks like this:". The output of what? What process did you apply to the input to generate this output, and how did you view the output?

Comment: @MadsHansen I confirm that the path is correct. I am verifying the ouput with Firefox AND Chrome

Comment: Try with IE. Some browsers(like FireFox and Chrome) have very strict security settings and will not load files entity references and XSLT processing instructions that reference files on the filesystm. What you are doing is valid XML and will work with XML parsers that adhere to the specs and are not locked down.

Comment: @MadsHansen Thx for the advices. I tried with libxml2 and it does work ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What you are doing is valid XML and will work with XML parsers that adhere to the specs and are not hobbled by security restrictions.**

Try viewing the XML in IE. Some browsers(like FireFox and Chrome) have very strict security settings and will not load files entity references and XSLT processing instructions that reference files on the filesystm.