# How to declare escape character as DTD Entities in external file and import in XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, entity, dtd

In a web project, I have a lot of XML files with non-escaped characters. I declare these characters as DTD Entities and include the list of declaration internally in each XML file, like so:

```
!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "../../pubmedref/archivearticle.dtd" [
   <!ENTITY bull "&#8226;">
   <!ENTITY copy "&#169;">
   ... a long list ...
]>
```

Is there any way I can have these declarations in an external file and import it in the XML files? The XML files are rendered to the browser using XSLT.

FWIW, I've tried referencing a `.ent` file but it does not work on any of the browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you would use a parameter entity...

**XML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "../../pubmedref/archivearticle.dtd" [
<!ENTITY % ents SYSTEM "../../pubmedref/entities.ent">
%ents;
]>
<article>...</article>
```

**Entity File** (you could have multiple files)

```
<!ENTITY bull "&#8226;">
<!ENTITY copy "&#169;">
```

However, most browsers will not resolve an external entity reference so you're stuck with having the entity declarations directly in the internal subset (between `[` and `]` in your doctype declaration).

Comment: I am really shocked. I can't believe this is not supported by the browsers. Any particular reason?

Comment: i stumbled across this old answer for kind of the same reasons. if think this part `<!ENTITY ents %` 
 should be corrected this way:
 `<!ENTITY % ents`

Comment: @MauroPanzeri - Excellent catch! Thank you!

Comment: @dpant > Some browsers(like FireFox and Chrome) have very strict security settings and will not load files entity references and XSLT processing instructions that reference files on the filesystm. 
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783578/how-to-use-external-entities-in-xml