# How to declare escape characters and import in XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, character, dtd

This question is related to : [How to declare escape character as DTD Entities in external file and import in XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343797/how-to-declare-escape-character-as-dtd-entities-in-external-file-and-import-in-x) but with a twist:

Is there a way to declare escape characters, found in a set of XML documents, in an external file and have it imported in the XML files, **othen than** using DTD Entity?

The XML documents are rendered using XSL.

Any non DTD related solution will do as long as all browsers support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is in general no way of declaring entities except with a DTD.